# How to build a single subproject from a Meson monorepo?

Tags: monorepo, meson-build, subproject

There is a Meson monorepo (for the record: [gstreamer](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer)) which contains multiple subprojects.

I am hacking one of the subprojects, and at least at the initial stage I would like to recompile only this subproject not trying to compile the rest of repo.

How to do it without significant changes in the project?